# get all dependencies for a maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, aether

hi 
is there a simple way i can get all dependencies for a maven project using java ( not the mvn console) or whats the algorithm used in mvn ? Thanks

Ive found  Model (org.apache.maven.model)
The code below works until it finds a variable (for example   '<'version>${mavenVersion}'<'/version>)

```
    System.out.println("dependency" + d.getArtifactId());
        if(d.isOptional()){
            return;
        }
        if(d.getVersion()==null){
            if(mod.getParent()!=null){

            try{

                MavenArtifact mart=new MavenArtifact();
                mart.setArtifactId(mod.getParent().getArtifactId());
                mart.setGroupId(mod.getParent().getGroupId());
                mart.setVersion(mod.getParent().getVersion());
                mart.setRepositoryUrl(mA.getRepositoryUrl());
                Model fMod = getModelFromPom(mart, p);
                if(fMod.getDependencyManagement()!=null){
                    for (Dependency dep : fMod.getDependencyManagement().getDependencies()) {
                        if(dep.getArtifactId().equals(d.getArtifactId())&dep.getGroupId().equals(d.getGroupId())){
                            getDependency(fMod, mart, p, dep);
                        }
                    }

                    for (Dependency dep : fMod.getDependencies()) {
                        if(dep.getArtifactId().equals(d.getArtifactId())&dep.getGroupId().equals(d.getGroupId())){
                            getDependency(fMod, mart, p, dep);
                        }
                    }
                }}


                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    view.showWarning("Could not find: groupId:"
                            + d.getGroupId() + " artifactId"
                            + d.getArtifactId() + " version:"
                            + d.getVersion());
                }
            }else{
                view.showWarning("Could not find: groupId:"
                        + d.getGroupId() + " artifactId"
                        + d.getArtifactId() + " version:"
                        + d.getVersion());


            }
        }else{
        MavenArtifact m = proxy.findDependency(d.getGroupId(), d
                .getArtifactId(), d.getVersion());

        if (m == null) {
            view.showWarning("Could not find: groupId:"
                    + d.getGroupId() + " artifactId"
                    + d.getArtifactId() + " version:"
                    + d.getVersion());

            return;
        }
        importMavenArtifact(m, p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the source of the maven-dependency-plugin if you want to match the behavior of 2.x. If you need to match 3.x, I think you have to learn about aether.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/), which is a wrapper around Aether. First, you will need to get a list of all project dependencies:

```
List<Artifact> deps = this.project.getDependencies();
```

Then, for every one of them you can get a list of all transitive dependencies:

```
File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

I may be wrong in details, but in general this is how it should work.

Comment: Looks  good  but I cant test it because  my project  was  abandoned  anyway +1